# Is there a clang-tidy check for returning a non-const reference from a const getter?

Tags: c++, static-analysis, clang-tidy

I would like to check our code for developers returning non-const reference in const methods.  Under normal circumstances a compiler would catch it, but if using PIMPL or pointers things get a little weird.

An example of how this is possible:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct PIMPL
{

    int x = 0;
};

struct Data
{
    std::unique_ptr<PIMPL> m_pimpl = std::make_unique<PIMPL>();

    // Signature is physically const correct, but logically const broken
    int& func() const
    {
        return m_pimpl->x;
    }

    int& func()
    {
        return m_pimpl->x;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Data dat1;
    const Data dat2;


    // OK
    dat1.func() = 2;
    // this should not be possible in the API
    dat2.func() = 44;

    std::cout << dat1.func() << std::endl;
    std::cout << dat2.func() << std::endl;

}
```

This is also valid in some weird edge cases.  I can see someone wanting to have a mutable field on a const class that uses pimpl, but would expect them to explicitly mark the field in the pimpl struct as mutable to clarify it even if it is not physically necessary.

After some searching on google and reading the docs I don't see an option in the clang-tidy documentation for this which surprises me.

In my mind it should be a check of:

- member function is const qualified
- is returning a reference type token
- return token is not const qualified
- if returning a member of something, that member is not marked mutable

Comment: Using [`std::experimental::propagate_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const) would catch it.

Comment: Change to `std::unique_ptr<PIMPL const> m_pimpl = std::make_unique<PIMPL const>();` would catch it.  In which case, it'd be convenient to have a `auto mutable_impl() -> PIMPL* { return const_cast<PIMPL*>(m_pimpl.get()); }`

Comment: @Eljay that last `const_cast` (well, the actual modification of the pointee through the returned pointer) is formally undefined behaviour as the original object is originally in fact, `const`. `const_cast` is only ever ok if the original object isn't `const`

Comment: @rubenb • Good catch, `std::unique_ptr<PIMPL const> m_pimpl{ new PIMPL };` so the original object is never `const`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Unfortunately I wasn't specific on our API.  since these headers are publicly exposed and need to be linked with a number of compilers I don't believe that is available.  It is a very cool feature though, I hope that one day soon enough compilers (and our users) will be able to support it.

Comment: Can be re-implemented easily though.